# running struts+tomcat6 application in linux+openJDK error

Tags: linux, struts2, tomcat6, jfreechart, java

I get the following exception when trying to run my application in eclipse.

```
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
    File: AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
    Method: connect
    Line: 158 - java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:158:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    ... 20 more
    Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/webapps/cute/WEB-         INF/lib    /struts2-jfreechart-plugin-2.3.4.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - Class:    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
File: AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 158 - java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:158:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:898)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: struts.apache.org - Class: java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
File: AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 158 - java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:158:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:893)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:158)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:174)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:814)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:755)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:680)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1005)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1258)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:259)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1167)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:977)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:624)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:486)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:810)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:740)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 27 more
```

I have configured the default server within Eclipse and added the jar files to the path.Placed the jar files in the lib folder.

Comment: hmmm, almost looks as if the problem is occurring when it is trying to retrieve the `.dtd` for a configuration file.  Maybe you could try copying and pasting the DTD into the top of your configuration files and see if the error goes away.  Of course, that's not a great "solution", but if it works then you have something that work's and a clue as to where the problem is.

Comment: I don't think i have a solution .Am not using any DTD's.

Comment: are you not using a struts.xml file?  if you are using it, then it likely references a dtd at the top in the form `<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">` .  Replace this with the dtd contents (which you can download from the URL).  do this for any config files you have, struts.xml, validation.xml files, etc.

Comment: btw, things get weird in openjdk sometimes.  i have had some issues recently with the play framework + jasper reports not resolving beans properly only on openjdk and we had to create a custom resolver.  oh the joy!

Comment: Yeah you were right.Internet Connection was the problem.Downloaded the DTD and now it is ok..Thanks@rees

Comment: sweet! no problem, im gonna add it as an answer i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive an exception like

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org

during the building of the Struts2 XML configuration, then something is preventing the application from successfully retrieving the `DTD`.

Changing the doctype declaration from

```
   <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
```

to either a local reference or just copying and pasting the DTD contents into its place will resolve the issue.

Comment: I would like to point this also . I was using struts2-jfreechart-plugin-2.3.4.jar and its struts-plugin.xml DTD was 2.3 and the one I had in my Struts.xml was 2.0. So Downloaded the struts2-jfreechart-plugin-2.1.8.jar and replaced it too. Thus resolved the problem. Thanks @rees.