# Struts2: Unable to load configuration

Tags: jar, struts2, struts

I get following Stacktrace when trying to start Tomcat7.
It shows me the path, but everthing including the content of the jar is placed correctly.

This error does only occur on this particular computer. All other computers are able download the same project from the repository and run it smoothly.

I deleted and reinstalled Tomcat, Eclipse and workspace.
This Version from the repository worked fine some days ago and suddenly without any change or update it throws this exception. If I revert to a version without the named jar it starts to work again on this computer - but as I said, it did work :)

Looking for the solution for two days now.

`

```
25.10.2012 13:34:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:380)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:424)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FIS/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.5.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:909)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Connection timed out: connect - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:904)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 21 more
25.10.2012 13:34:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error filterStart
25.10.2012 13:34:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/FIS] startup failed due to previous errors
```

`

Comment: Please add some more details as to what your project consists of (at least what dependencies does it contain, other than Struts), how do you build and deploy it (do you build it with Eclipse, and then deploy it via Eclipse to a Tomcat that's also configured inside Eclipse, can you also build it some other way (manually even) and manually deploy it into a non-Eclipse-related Tomcat, and if so, do you get the same errors).

Comment: Check out this question and answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328100/running-strutstomcat6-application-in-linuxopenjdk-error/12363589#12363589  Also, look at the asker's comment on the answer:  make sure your plugins and your Struts2 version have compatible DTDs.

Comment: check out if you got this file: `file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FIS/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.5.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml` I suggest you check your dependency, delete your server from eclipse, and build and run this project again using a new server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not deploying it twice (because your project works on some machines and not on just once), maybe it's a machine problem.

Then i would check internet settings, proxies (with exceptions), firewalls, etc...

The easiest way to do is to compare all of them with a pretty identical machine where the software works, instead of analyzing them one by one...

I know that this is obvious, but the information you posted are really not enough to try something specific, and even with struts config posted, if there's at least one place where the software works, i think it's a environment configuration problem, not a software problem...

Comment: I removed the proxy details (Preferences -> Network connections -> MANUAL to DIRECT), also I switched my connection to one without proxys and now it starts perfectly. Never thought about the fact, that all the other computers have no proxies inbetween. Especially because all necesarry files are available locally.